# MySQL Child objects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table which has a parent child relationship as shown below

```
  id   Name   parent_id 
  1    F1      0   
  2    F2      0
  3    S1      1
  4    S3      2
  5    S4      4
  6    S5      4
  7    S6      4
```

Presently i would like to get the date such that when i query for Id='2', i would need all the childs associated with that parent id.

with the below query i'm able to get only 1 level childs

```
      SELECT r.* FROM category r 
      left JOIN category a on a.parent_id = r.id
      left join category  b on b.parent_id = a.id
      left join category  c on c.parent_id = b.id
      where r.id  = '2'
```

here is the result i would like to see

```
          id     Name   parent_id
          4      S3      2
          5      S4      4
          6      S5      4
          7      S6      4
```

Comment: Can you post your desired output as well

Comment: If i query for id ='2', then i would need the row's for id= 2,4,5,6,7

Comment: update your question with the desire output properly formated

Comment: updated my question